# Error with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Tags: php, forms

For some reasons, that are unclear for me, I can't use this code on my website: when I use it the `php` form doesn't load.

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";
$email = (filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));       
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

This one works but it doesn't give an error when there isn't a `.` after the `@` in the email, so the email below get validated

```
$email = "john.doe@examplecom";
$email = (filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

How can I get my form to validate only email with an `@` and a `.` after the `@`

Edit:

```
        $authorEmail = (filter_var($_POST['formEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
        if (!(filter_var($authorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){
            $emailError = true;
            $hasError = true;
        } else{
            $formEmail = $authorEmail;
        };
```

Comment: try use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false` without the `!`, or you can just remove `!`

Comment: The second email address is valid. There's no reason why `filter_var` should return false. `user@domain` is perfectly valid, the TLD is not required by any standard

Comment: I have no idea, I just `var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));` and it return `false`, maybe becoz the filter follows RFC 822

Comment: @Andrew simply removing the `!` also gave me a blank space where the `php` form should have loaded

Comment: @Arone I was trying to point out `$email = "john.doe@examplecom";` will return `false` which should show invalid instead of valid, sry if I phrase my words wrongly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to enforce validation that is *too* strict. your second example (*"john.doe@examplecom"*) is a valid email address according to the relevant RFC standards (5321, 5322 and 6531). Other valid email addresses include:

- "()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
- user@[IPv6:2001:db8::1]
- user@com

This one has to be posted as code because it contains so many weird characters:

```
#!$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
```

### [examples taken from email wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

The *closest* you can get to an RFC compliant home-grown validation system is to use an insanely complex regex: [like this one](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: damn, I want to get an email like this `#!$%&'*+-/=?^_\`{}|~@example.org`, where can I sign up ?!

Comment: Referring to your suggested regex : the first example my question recognize john.doe@examplecom as an invalid email so I don't quite get why I would need such a regex. Do you suggest I should accept in my contact form an email like john.doe@examplecom?

Comment: @Arone: Yes, you should accept it, because it's a valid email address. Although not very likely to be in use, some hosts do allow the use of quotes in an email address (I've seen one that allows you to register `"."@host.org`). not allowing those email addresses would, to my mind, be a mistake. The only way to accurately validate an email address anyway is by sending a confirmation message

Comment: So if I get you right,  I should remove this line `$email = (filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));`?

Comment: @Arone: Yup, if you're validating user input, validate the actual input, don't use `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` first. Always validate the actual data, if not, you might end up storing a different string than the one the user posted, which obviously poses problems